# If you are using an interface-based design approach, how do you name the more behavioural interfaces?

Tags: java, oop, interface, naming-conventions

I'm developing a library containing multiple controls (or components). I'm using an interface based approach to type design, but eventually it led me to a question that bothers me for a long time. If you use an interface-based design approach, how do yo name the behaviour interfaces? For example, let's assume you have some getter setter functions and they're used by many interfaces, and functionality they provide is cannot be named with a "-able" postfix; what would you do, or do you do? Thanks...

Edit: For example i created an interface like this:

```
public interface HasText {

    public String getText();

    public void setText(String text);

}
```

most interfaces that use this functions has no common super type.

Comment: Examples will lead to good answers! (BTW, "-able" is a *postfix*)

Comment: suffix, to be precise :)

Comment: @Bozho - yes, you're right, 'suffix' sounds much better (but, OTH at wikipedia: "In linguistics, a suffix (also sometimes called a **postfix** or ending) is an affix which is placed after the stem of a word.")

Comment: yes. I think there is small difference, which I can't explain, though :)

Comment: One thing you want to be careful about with Has interfaces is the case where you'd want more than 1 of the same kind of property, e.g. 2 different Text fields.  It really depends on the problem you're working on.  If you have a lot of runtime type checks to see if something implements the HasText interface, there's probably a better way to do whatever you're trying to do.

Comment: It's not for runtime checks and in all cases i don't need the same feature more than once (getText means just get the text property, not get a property which is a text), i just wantws to declare an interface that has a lot of features easily by extending has... interfaces. Thanks for useful information, voted up...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Name the interface as a word or phrase correctly describing any class that implements it.  "HasText" is a fine example as it describes the implementor (it has a Text property).

Make it specific to the interface.  "IsAnObject" or "MightHaveData" or "ExistsInCyberspace" is not specific to the interface.

Answer (score 1):

Sure that you need different behaviour interfaces? Wouldn't it be enough to implement one behaviour interface and a couple of concrete behaviours?

Just an example, assume we have an imlplementation of a real wild animal, say a class `Cat` with some sensors and a big catalog of behaviours. Now the cat's eye-sensor reports "mouse!!". The `Cat` will query it's `Collection` of `Behaviour` instances if there's a fit, iaw, if any of the stored `Behaviour` instances likes to take action. Assume we have an instance of `class HuntMouse implements Behaviour` stored in the list and this is the best fit, then the cat would call `action()` on that `Behaviour` and hunt the mouse.

Back to your question - I think, one `Behaviour` interface with 2-3 methods would be enough, concrete `Behaviour` objects do not need a prefix or suffix. And if needed, I suggest `-Behaviour` (like `HuntMouseBehaviour`)

---

Initially you asked for *Behaviours* but your `HasText` example shows some kind of *Feature*. Where in this special case, `TextProvider` could be an a better choice while `hasText` is more suiteable. Implementing the interface adds the `provide some text` feature to the class.

---

Not as an answer to the question but for further reading: [List of behavioural design patterns](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?CategoryBehavioralPatterns).

(BTW - my example above was inspired by real implementations from the robotics area - even though a cat is not a robot ;))

Comment: to be more precise, i'm trying to group common properties between some interfaces, i dont want to use command-like approach because specialized methods like getName() are more readable than get("name").

Comment: Having a Behavior interface, collections of unknown behaviors, etc. is fine if you have specific need for it, but isn't such need an exception, not the rule?  Two advantages to using getName() instead of get("Name") are that getName gives you static typing (it returns a string, getDate() returns a DateTime, but get("propertyName") returns an object), and that strings (e.g. "Name") do not play well with refactoring tools--e.g., if you want to change "Name" to "PersonName", you have to resort to find-and-replace.

Comment: @apollodude217 - the example that Deniz added yesterday, is not an interface for a *Behaviour* but more for a *Feature*. You wouldn't say something like: 'the class behaves like having a text', it's more like: 'the class has the provide-text feature'. And of course, one would not use inheritance for the main class, not 'a cat **is-a** behaviour' but 'a cat **has-a** behaviour'. Only behaviours would implement a `Behaviour` interface.

Comment: it is a good example of course, just not what i was looking for; but thanks for useful information, voting up...